# What encoding is Banned Suffix List?

Tags: encoding, string

Mozilla maintains a effective TLD or banned suffix list at [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/) and its wiki [Public Suffix List](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List).

Most entries are straight forward, but some are confusing to me since I don't work with i18n often. For example, 組織.hk.

Would anyone know what the encoding for the list is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What encoding is Banned Suffix List?

The encoding is UTF-8. I was using the `dat` file from the source code which lacked comments. The [Public Suffix List page](http://publicsuffix.org/list/) calls out the format and some parsing rules.